# How are skills stored in the human brain?

Tags: brain, memory

How are skills stored in the human brain? I understand the difference between STM and LTM (short/long term memory). However, remembering a fact is different than learning a skill.

Example: Let's take a 99% mental-only skill like Software Engineering.
You understand that IF this, THEN that, ELSE something-else. That's how you define a really basic piece of decision logic. There are many more complex forms of that which can become very abstract. At some point, you understand all of them (maybe even for dozens of languages) and you understand it so well, you subconsciously take a requirement and translate it into possibly hundreds of lines of code within seconds. This seems similar to the way people learn to read/write and speak multiple languages.

Is this simply a function of LTM which translates bits of code into actions / results? If so, how does that LTM become more readily accessible than other areas of LTM where one has to think harder to remember something? Or when it comes to learned skills (vs just facts), is this a different kind of memory entirely?

Comment: Good question, +1. But doesn't it belong to [biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/775/how-and-where-in-the-human-brain-are-memories-stored)?

Comment: Maybe it does... I guess my reasons for asking are actual health related reasons. But, since I didn't specify that - maybe it's more biology. Should I move it myself or wait till it is flagged? lol

Comment: Anyone who can provide a provably correct answer to this question needs to get off stackexchange and go collect their Nobel prize.